# SQL to compare values separated by space

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Dears,

I have values in my oracle table like below:

Values are separated by space. I need to check if all the values present in value1 columns are present in value2. If yes, update the isMatch by 'Y'.

[image]

I am able to do it PLSQL by as my table contain 2 million records, it is taking very much time.

Can this be done via SQL?

------ Update on padaleiana's answer ---- 
Please find explain plan below:
[image]

I have added the /*+ ORDERED USE_HASH(b) append */ hint as well as create indexes on value1 and value2 but still cost is too high.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each value columns might individually be splitted, ordered, and  then joined. During the join, equality of each splitted pieces is checked out by comparing with the maximum number of distinctly picked pieces with respect to each ID values of the original table. So, use the following query :

```
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(value1,'[^ ]+',1,level) AS value1, level AS cnt
   FROM t -- original table
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(value1,' ') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR ID = ID
 ORDER BY value1
), t2 AS
(
 SELECT DISTINCT ID, REGEXP_SUBSTR(value2,'[^ ]+',1,level) AS value2, level AS cnt
   FROM t
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(value2,' ') + 1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR ID = ID
 ORDER BY value2
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, 
       CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t1.value1 = t2.value2 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID)
                = MAX(t1.cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ID) 
            THEN
               'Y'
            ELSE
               'N'
             END AS ismatch
  FROM t 
  LEFT JOIN t1  
    ON t1.ID = t.ID     
  LEFT JOIN t2
    ON t2.ID = t1.ID   
   AND t1.value1 = t2.value2
 ORDER BY t.ID;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0d697a934cb1c48f3c26510c200affca)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. I will test and let you know the result.

Comment: you're welcome @Wolfgang . Btw, those hints mostly adverly impact the performance. Since for latest versions of Oracle(10g+ I can say) the cost based optimizer takes roles for performance tuning and optimization rather than hints. Indeed, it's better to hold that type of data splitted into row-wise manner in order to manage with greater performance gain. For current data you cannot even exploit the advantages of creating index.

Comment: Thanks @Barboros, It gave me perfect result. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there are better and more optimal solutions, but one solution could be the below (assuming your table is called `table1`):

```sql
MERGE INTO table1 t1
USING table1 t2 ON (regexp_count(t2.value1, replace(t1.value1, ' ', '|')) =
        regexp_count(t1.value2, replace(t1.value1, ' ', '|')))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.isMatch = 'Y';
```

[`MERGE` command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) is like an *upsert*. In this case, you only need to use `WHEN MATCHED THEN...` because you don't want to insert new values if not matched rows are found.
[`REGEXP_COUNT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014) indicates the number of occurrences of a pattern in a string. Here, the pattern is `replace(t1.value1, ' ', '|')` (replacing whitespace with `|`) and the string is `t1.value1`.

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=94bbaf1d5fc8df403fa56aae578ceb17).

Comment: Thanks padaleiana for the input. However cost is too high to execute this query. I will add explain plan in the question.